# GSM serial get event or read the whole input?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, gsm, shields

I am using an Arduino Uno with GSM shield, trying to read some SMS. Here is my code.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);

char incoming_char=0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(19200); // for serial monitor
  SIM900.begin(19200); // for GSM shield
  SIM900power();  // turn on shield
  delay(20000);  // give time to log on to network.

  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");  // set SMS mode to text
  delay(100);
  SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r"); 

  delay(100);
}

void loop()
{
  // Now we simply display any text that the GSM shield sends out on the serial monitor
  if(SIM900.available() >0)
  {
    incoming_char=SIM900.read(); //Get the character from the cellular serial port.
    Serial.print(incoming_char); //Print the incoming character to the terminal.
  }
}
```

My issue is: am testing sending this sms to the shield

> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z

but somehow am not getting all the info, why?

[image]